# change text of active admin has_many_remove button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

How do I change the text on the Remove (the one assigned class 'has_many_remove') button on an active admin f.has_many stanza from 'Remove' to 'Hide'?  Only for the current page/model and not site-wide.

Comment: For page-specific renaming, you need to involve some JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed this feature is missing from Active Admin, see the discussion in the issues section of the Active Admin github repo: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/5283

Answer (score 0):

For **application-wide** change, you just need to add the following inside `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  active_admin:
    has_many_remove: "Hide"
```

But for **page-specific** change, you need some help from JS.

p.s. I can update the answer with js solution if you can provide your specific needs.

Comment: my question was regarding a page-specific change.

Comment: My original post specified "only for the current page/model and not-site-wide".  "Use JS" isn't a helpful answer.